# there are at most finitely many points

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value

I have the formula $\frac{2a_{i}}{a^{2}_{i}+1}=-b_{i}$ and I want to show that $|a_{i}|=1$ only when $|b_{i}|\geq1$ which is easy to prove but my question is how I can prove the statement " there are at most finitely many $|a_{i}|=1$ ?"

I appreciate any help..

Comment: Is $a_i$ a real number? In that case the only $a_i$ that fulfill the condition are $a_i = \pm 1$, which is a finite set.

Comment: how about if they are complex?

Comment: You have a degree 2 polynomial in $a_i$ : b_ia_i^2+2a_i+b_i$ which has a finite number (actually 2) of roots.

Comment: but if we have an inequality then we are not restricted to only two roots :)

Comment: In your heading, is "infinitely" a typo for "finitely"?

Comment: @bof: The title is the only reason I clicked on this, so maybe this was intentional to get more people to look at the question. I suspect that was not the case here, but it got me to wonder whether anyone has actually tried something like that in Stack Exchange.

Comment: sorry I should correct the title it is my mistake the correct is "finitely" ..\

Comment: Yeah, but what's the difference between "finitely many" and "at most finitely many"? Is there such a thing as "less than finitely many"?

Answer (score 0):

You have a degree 2 polynomial in $a_i$ : b_ia_i^2+2a_i+b_i$ which has a finite number (actually 2) of roots.